# Configure Play! 2 models to use a specific database in multiple databases environments

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I'm using Play! 2.0.4 (Java version), and I need to access 2 different databases (in fact 2 separated schemas). So in my `application.conf`, I've defined that:

```
db.default.driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
db.default.url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@server:1234:SCHEMA1"
db.default.user=user1
db.default.password=password1

db.bar.driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
db.bar.url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@server:1234:SCHEMA2"
db.bar.user=user2
db.bar.password=password2
```

Now, I have a model that I need to *link* with the `bar` database.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_BAR")
public class Bar extends Model {

    ...

    public static Finder<Integer, Bar> finder = new Finder<Integer, Bar>(Integer.class, Bar.class);

    public static Bar findOne() {
        return finder.where().[some conditions].findUnique();
    }

}
```

Of course this will not work as Play will try to access the database defined in the `default` connection.

So my question is how can I configure my `Model` to always use the `bar` connection?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's showed in [documentation at the beggining](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/JavaEbean) In your case it will be something like this:

```
ebean.default="models.Foo,models.A,models.B,models.C"
ebean.bar="models.Bar"
```

Note that if you are splitting models between different DBs you can not use wildcard notation anymore:

> ebean.default="models.*"
>
> ebean.bar="models.Bar"